# Print result from midway through a chunk of piped code without saving a temporary object

Tags: r, tidyverse

Often I would like to print some results or values from part way through a chunk of piped code without stopping to save my code as a temporary object that gets picked up in the next chunk.

The code below will output a series of anova tables. Is there a way that I could interrupt my lines of code to print the results of "group_by(cyl) %>% count", before the code continues on to create the anova models?

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(
    am = factor(am, labels = c("auto", "manual")),
    vs = factor(vs, labels = c("V", "S"))
  ) %>% 
  # group_by(cyl) %>% count %>% 
  split(.$cyl) %>% 
  map(~anova(lm(mpg ~ am * carb + , data = .)))
```

This code produces the outputs I want to view, but requires me to create a temporary object (i.e., temp), which clutters my environment.

```
(temp <- 
  mtcars %>%
  mutate(
    am = factor(am, labels = c("auto", "manual")),
    vs = factor(vs, labels = c("V", "S"))
  )
) %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% count 

temp %>% 
  split(.$cyl) %>% 
  map(~anova(lm(mpg ~ am * carb, data = .)))
```

Comment: If you don't want unnecessary objects to clutter your environment, perhaps you can remove them? i.e. run the code `rm(temp)`.

Comment: @HNSKD, I understand how to remove objects from my environment, but I thought there might be special pipes or operators that print a result before continuing on to the additional operations in the code chunk